# How to add custom fields to SearchAPI

Tags: entities, search

On D7 and search api I could use hook_entity_property_info_alter() to add custom properties to nodes and these where indexed also by SearchAPI, so that I could fill them with custom values, something like this:

```
function mymodule_view_entity_property_info_alter(&$info) {
  $info['node']['properties']['custom_property'] = array(
    'type' => 'taxonomy_term',
    'label' => t('Label'),
    'sanitized' => TRUE,
    'getter callback' => '_function_get_value',
  );
}
```

On D8 there isn't this hook, so how should I add properties to an entity with custom values?

The purpose is to use this custom properties, with calculated values, as facets on some SearchApi views.

Comment: Entity properties are gone, everything is in fields now (base or custom). I'm not sure the pseudo/fake field concept that the entity API module allowed made its way over, maybe just use a field?

Comment: So I should "simply" add a "dynamic" field so that when SearchAPI indexes that node, the value is calculated "live". But, if it's in this way, I could simply add a "normale" boolean value that is filled when I save the node, or not?

Comment: I guess it depends on your requirement - if you need to calculate something right before it's indexed there's probably a way to do that, but if it's something that could be calculated on each entity save, that would make more sense I think

Comment: I don't need a classic custom field, because I don't need o save this value in database or display it. I need "simply" to fill a searchapi field (I use solr as backend) with a dynamic value.

Comment: Anyway the simplest way is to create a normal field and set value on node_presave or something like this..

Comment: Use hook_entity_base_field_info(). See [question 241344](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/241344/what-is-the-equivalent-of-hook-property-info-alter).