# What is the equivalent of hook_property_info_alter()?

Tags: 8, entities

In Drupal 7, The [Entity API](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity/) module uses  [`hook_entity_property_info()`](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_property_info/7) and [`hook_entity_property_info_alter()`](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_property_info_alter/7) which allowed us to add custom properties. (Not everything is a field.)

I can't find anything related to Drupal 8. The only thing I find is how to add it on a custom entity. How should I add properties to an existing entity/bundle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose you want [hook_entity_base_field_info()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_base_field_info/8.2.x). By using a computed field based on a class, you can get a behavior similar to properties.

```
function hook_entity_base_field_info(\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeInterface $entity_type) {
  if ($entity_type->id() == 'node') {
    $fields = [];
    $fields['mymodule_text'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('string')
      ->setLabel(t('The text'))
      ->setDescription(t('A text property added by mymodule.'))
      ->setComputed(TRUE)
      ->setClass('\Drupal\mymodule\EntityComputedText');

    return $fields;
  }
}
```

I have copied a snippet from Drupal commerce, where a payment gateway reference is appended to a commerce_order entity (commerce_payment module altering an entity from commerce_order module).

```
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_base_field_info().
 */
function commerce_payment_entity_base_field_info(EntityTypeInterface $entity_type) {
  if ($entity_type->id() === 'commerce_order') {
    $fields['payment_gateway'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('entity_reference')
      ->setLabel(t('Payment gateway'))
      ->setDescription(t('The payment gateway.'))
      ->setRequired(TRUE)
      ->setSetting('target_type', 'commerce_payment_gateway');

    $fields['payment_method'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('entity_reference')
      ->setLabel(t('Payment method'))
      ->setDescription(t('The payment method.'))
      ->setRequired(TRUE)
      ->setSetting('target_type', 'commerce_payment_method');

    return $fields;
  }
}
```

By using `->setReadOnly(TRUE);` or `->setComputed(TRUE)`, you can probably hide them from regular forms, making them behave like properties.